# Why the cypress click not working with ionic (tap) event

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, cypress

I am not able to actual click and trigger the event by .click() of cypress if my html element is having (tap) event which I have included for ionic

HTML

```
< img data-cy="submit-env" tabindex="0" (tap)="secretTap()">
```

Cypress

cy.get('[data-cy=submit-env]')
         .click()

It's not working as expect It's working when I change (tap) with (click) like
 < img data-cy="submit-env" tabindex="0" (click)="secretTap()">

Comment: have you tried using (click) instead of (tap) in your template?

Comment: Yes , If I use (click) than its working but I want to be working on (tap)